# How index affects insertion

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a problem where I am trying to figure out the reason for slow insertion. I need to know if the insertion is going to be faster for *scenario A* or not.

*Scenario A*:

```
insert into tableA (orgid, accountid, name)
    values ('abc','123','A');
// orgid abc has 10 records against it in the table.
```

*Scenario B*:

```
insert into tableA (orgid, accountid, name)
    values ('def','123','A');
// orgid def has 10000 records against it in the table.
```

The index is on `orgid`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: we are using oracle

Comment: Which type of index is on `orgid`? BITMAP or B-TREE?

Comment: I don't know to be honest, but can you please let me know if any type will cause the scenario mentioned above?

Comment: Does the table has any triggers or foreign key constraints?

Comment: Yes, it has plenty.

Comment: @SadiqAli . . . If you are seeing a difference in performance please include that in the question.

Comment: I am able to see a difference in performance, but so far it is just a hunch that somehow indexing is responsible for this.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the time to do an insertion is not going to be affected (very much) by the *values* that are currently in the table.  The number of rows is not going to have much effect either.

Performance will be affected significantly by having indexes, foreign key constraints, check constraints, and triggers.

It is possible that you have a trigger that is somehow related to the number of rows with a particular value in a table.  However, in Oracle, this would typically be a mutating table trigger, so even that seems unlikely.